# «Удачи вам(,) и вспомните обо мне, когда добьётесь успеха». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

> Удачи вам(,) и вспомните обо мне, когда добьётесь успеха.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Удачи вам, и вспомните обо мне, когда добьётесь успеха.**
([Я желаю] Удачи вам, и [вы] вспомните обо мне, когда добьётесь успеха.)

Это сложносочиненное предложение, состоящее из двух неполных. В первом (повествовательном) предложении пропущены подлежащее и сказуемое, во втором (побудительном) — подлежащее.

Два разных по цели высказывания предложения — общего второстепенного члена нет, общего придаточного нет, общего вводного слова нет, при прочтении перед "и" необходимо сделать паузу. И поставить запятую. (Можно и восклицательный знак.)

[Запятая перед союзом «И»](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html?start=1)